# Loading data in the file (which is in FTP over SSH) using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssh, ssis, ftp, sftp

I have SSIS package that is loading data into a file. Currently the file is in network drive , but my manager want this file in **FTP over SSH** server. I don't see any task SSIS that can do this. I know FTP task does not work here. Can some one please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the Execute Process task, depends on what you are using to connect but if it is something like WinSCP then [here](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis) is an example

Comment: Dave thanks for the answer                                                                   SFTP and FTP over SSH are they both same ..?

Comment: Yes SFTP is FTP over SSH

Comment: Strictly speaking [FTP over SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#FTP_over_SSH) is not SFTP. FTP over SSH is FTP tunneled through SSH. But this combination is rarely, if ever, used. So generally, when people use FTP over SSH as an incorrect name for SFTP (that has nothing to do with FTP).

Answer (score 5):

WinSCP provides an SFTP task for SSIS:

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis

SFTP is often referred to as FTP over SSH, so this is the sort of thing you're looking for. If you already have an SFTP task available, use that instead. You will still need credentials for the SFTP server once you figure out which task you need to use.

Comment: Is there a SFTP task in SSIS ?  I don't see any SFTP task in SSIS. i am using  VS-2012

Comment: There's no SFTP task in SSIS (natively). But you can use [*Execute Process* task](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis) to execute WinSCP script. Or create an [SSIS package using WinSCP .NET assembly](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis).